# How do I code this loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want the user to enter a number and print out messages according to the value of the number they input.

```
a=int(input("enter a number"))

while a<1:
    int(input("enter another number please"))

if a>0 and a<7:
    print a,"medium value number"

elif a>6:
    print a,"high value number"
```

The problem with it is that if I enter a number lower than 1 (0,-1,-2 and so on) the loop doesn't stop if I input a number that meets the requirements of the other to conditionals (higher than 0).

I tried integrating *break* after the *while* function but it only works once as it will ask the user for an input only once.

Comment: In cycle you had missed: `a= int(input("enter another number please"))`. You have to assign input value to `a`.

Comment: Darn @StanleyR you're a fast typer, just about to say that :)

Comment: @StanleyR Thanks! That was just what I needed. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to assign variable 'a' to Input

```
a=int(input("enter a number"))

while a<1:
    #assign 'a' Here
    a=int(input("enter another number please"))          

if a>0 and a<7:
    print (a,"medium value number")

elif a>6:
    print (a,"high value number")
```